# installing "ia32-libs" problem - Ubuntu 12.10 x64

Tags: 12.10, package-management

I'm trying to install ia32-libs and i tried nearly all commands to install this package but always i got an error. Here is what i've tried so far;

**sudo apt-get install ia32libs**

```
orkun@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32libs
[sudo] password for orkun: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'ferramroberto-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ferramroberto-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ferramroberto-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package ia32libs
```

.

**sudo apt-get install package-name:i386**

```
orkun@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'ferramroberto-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ferramroberto-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package package-name
```

.

Downloading [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/20090808ubuntu36) package and trying these commands;

sudo dpkg -i «package name>

```
orkun@ubuntu:~/İndirilenler$ sudo dpkg -i ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 151309 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ia32-libs 20090808ubuntu36 (using ia32-libs_20090808ubuntu36_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ia32-libs ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-libs:
 ia32-libs depends on ia32-libs-multiarch; however:
  Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not installed.

dpkg: error processing ia32-libs (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your APT doesn't have an i386 foreign architecture. I have no idea why this happens to people...

Try:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete novice here, so I suspect that this has **not** been overlooked, but it looks like you're missing a "-" in your first line of code.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I just installed  "ia32-libs" on Ubuntu 12.10 x86 as above for a JDK7u9 and NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 installation (apparently there is no 64-bit bundle).

Comment: This gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at first. Then I tried a few methods to solve it. The one that worked is like the following:

1. Make sure the server you selected in the "Software Sources" is the "Main Server".
2. Search for all packages starting with "lib32" with `apt-cache search lib32`.
3. Install every package that's in the list and without any "-dbg" or "-dev" suffixes.
4. Then you can try to install the "ia32-libs" again.

This worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libc6-i386/download

   > sudo apt-get -f install
2. Then execute the following commands :

   > sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   >
   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: Added `sudo` as all these commands as to be run as root.